# Marketing Cloud Query activity using DateAdd() to get records

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I am trying to use this query to add records with a 'dateofApplication' date of 15 days ago:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [UG Journey Master]
WHERE [dateofApplication] = DateAdd(day,-15,GetDate())
```

Unfortunately, it adds 0 records to my data extension.
The first part is correct, as when I use a different WHERE clause (such as Email_Address Like 'Z%') works fine. So there is something wrong with my DateAdd clause.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to consider the time portion of the dates.  Here's a [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/812377) way to do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [UG Journey Master]
WHERE [dateofApplication] >= DateAdd(day,-15,cast(GetDate() as date))
and [dateofApplication] < DateAdd(day,-14,cast(GetDate() as date))
```

Casting `getDate()` as a `date`, will reset the time part of the date to zero (midnight).

**Update (20170804)**

Here's a more efficient way to do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [UG Journey Master]
WHERE [dateofApplication] >= convert(date,getDate()-15)
and [dateofApplication] < convert(date,getDate()-14)
```

Comment: Follow up question @AdamSpriggs - I am currently constructing a query that will add people into a data extension when their event_date is 28, 21, 14 or 7 days away. I currently use WHERE [Event_StartDate] >= DateAdd(day,28,cast(GetDate() as date))
AND [Event_StartDate] < DateAdd(day,29,cast(GetDate() as date)) to get those 28 days away, but how would I write the rest of it to add those people 21 or 14 days away? I'm not sure whereabouts the 'ORs' and 'ANDs' need to go.

Comment: Please post a new question.